# Is there a way to get Excel to work with a zero in the exponent?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using Excel to get some hairy calculations done (a significance test on a trinomial distribution, ugly!) and I just noticed that when I enter a formula like `=D47^0`, I get a `#NUMBER` error, when math textbooks insist that I should get a 1.

Is this a bug and if yes, how come nobody noticed it before?! Am I doing something wrong? Is there a workaround other than use a IF formula which checks for a zero in the exponent?

I already tried using the "normal" POWER(number;exponent) formula instead of the shortcut circumflex, without success.

Comment: Why is this a problem (not making fun of; genuinly interested) if you know it equals 1?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2003 and it correctly evaluated that as 1.  I even put the exponent in a separate cell and plugged the cell reference into the formula and it worked fine.

Comment: The formula for a trinomial distribution contains 3 exponential terms. I am using the formula up to 20 times per data set, and I have 38 data sets now, but expect more in the future. Manually inserting 1 everywhere is too much (error-prone) work, and using if($E52<>0;D47^$E52;1) instead of D47^$E52 everywhere bloats an already unreadable formula to a non-debuggable monstrosity, because I don't have the space on the sheet to calculate each term in its own cell, so the whole trinomial formula goes into a single cell, the ones I posted are the fourth level of nesting.

Comment: This worked fine for me--evaluating to 1. Can you give an example of the numbers you are working with?

Comment: Understood. Yes, that makes sense. I also just tried (I wasn't on a machine that had Excel before) evaluating in several ways some number^0, and in all cases it worked out fine. Could you provide a working example of where the error occurs (Excel 2007 here).

Comment: @Rook, r.e. why 0^0=1 may be useful: I arrived here just now from testing geometric series in excel.  I know it is a little late but here's a reason.  Excerpt from link:  "The question of what value 0^0 (0^0) should evaluate to has been discussed since the time of Euler (1700s). There are three candidate choices: 1,0, or “indeterminate” (i.e., throw an error).

In this article, I argue that the only reasonable choice (for discrete mathematics) is 0^0=1 (0^0 = 1), and I’ll give a tangible, feel-the-grit-in-your-palms reason why..."
link: http://mathscitech.org/articles/zero-to-zero-power

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Excel correctly gives you  1 as long as D47 is not 0.  If you try to take 0^0, only THIS is equal to "#NUM!".  The mathematical reason is x^0 is always 1, but 0^x is always 0, so 0^0 is undefined.

Comment: Thank you, you found it out. Only after you told me this, I noticed that the exponent and base in my case are calculated (using two different methods) from the same data set, so whenever the calculation for the exponent gives a zero, the calculation for the base also results in a zero. I must have been staring at cells for too long to not notice it myself :(

Comment: Depending on your spreadsheet software, it may actually evaluate to 1. Google Sheets does this, as does LibreOffice.